# How to make listings display characters special characters

Tags: listings, unicode, font-encodings, listingsutf8

I am trying to show a directory structure of a tree using the listings package like so:

```
├── controllers
│   ├── application_controller.rb
```

what I get looks like this:

```
    controllers
            application_controller.rb
```

when I use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

the error given is:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:\lst@FillFixed@\lst@EC not set up for use with LaTeX. [├── ]
```

trying with utf8x gives:

```
./directory_listing.txt:1: Package utf8x Error: MalformedUTF-8sequence. [├── ]
```

and

```
[U+FFFD][U+FFFD][U+FFFD]
1
controllers
[U+FFFD][U+FFFD][U+FFFD]
2
[U+FFFD][U+FFFD][U+FFFD]
a p p l i c a t i o n _ c o n t r o l l e r . rb
```

and

```
âŤIJâŤĂâŤĂ controllers
âŤĆÂăÂă âŤIJâŤĂâŤĂ application_controller.rb
```

If I do not include the utf8 line.

Is there a way to get it to correctly encode the emdashes, pipes and three way pipes so that they show in the output? (P.s. I need some form of [T1]fontenc or underscores are not displayed correctly elsewhere.)

Comment: Try the `dirtree` package, it is better suited in what you are trying to do.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides thanks, this package looks helpful, is there a way to include this package within a listing as I have a lot of listings along with a listings contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a work-around, using the [`pmboxdraw`](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pmboxdraw.pdf) package and `listings`' `escapechar` command, that allows to insert Latex code in listings environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Here is my code (note that I can insert \LaTeX code between ``@''):

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]
for i in @\LaTeX@:
    print @$\sum_i$@
\end{lstlisting}

Now, let's print the characters you are interrested in:

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]
@\pmboxdrawuni{251D}\pmboxdrawuni{2501}@ controllers
@\textSFxi@  @\pmboxdrawuni{251D}\pmboxdrawuni{2501}\pmboxdrawuni{2501}@ application_controller.rb
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There might be Lualatex or XeLaTex solutions to use unicode characters: would that be an option for you?